# List / Grid / Tile view transitions using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I want to achieve **list / grid / tile** view using Jquery/JS.
[image]

I have surfed a lot regarding grid/list view with animation, but got only grid/list view solutions. **but i need grid/list view along with animation(i,e tranistion effect)**. I have attached sample [video](https://vimeo.com/643360913) of the transition effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my basic implementation. I've tried to create output like the video. 
 The idea is to wrap list item in a wrapper. Wrappers are statically placed and list items are absolutely placed. When view changes wrapper gets arranged automatically as per stylesheet or container rules. But move list items after with animations.

```js
var pos = [];
var offs = null;

function init() {
  offs = $(".container").first().offset();
  $(".wrapper").each(function (i) {
    updatePositions();
    $(this).children(0).css({
      top: pos[i].top,
      left: pos[i].left
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  init();
})

function updatePositions() {
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    var tp = $(this).offset().top - offs.top;
    var lf = $(this).offset().left - offs.left;
    pos[index] = {
      top: tp,
      left: lf
    };
  });
}

function grid() {
  if ($(".wrapper").first().hasClass("gv-wrapper")) return;
  updatePositions();
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("dv-wrapper cv-wrapper");
    $(this).addClass("gv-wrapper");

    $(this).children(0).css({
      opacity: 0.8,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    });
  });

  updatePositions();
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children(0).children(0).removeClass("dv-video cv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).removeClass("dv-details cv-details");
    $(this).children(0).children(0).first().addClass("gv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).last().addClass("gv-details");
    $(this).children(0).animate({
      height: "100px",
      width: "200px",
      opacity: 1,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    }, 1000, "swing");
  });
}


function detailed() {
  if ($(".wrapper").first().hasClass("dv-wrapper")) return;

  updatePositions();

  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("gv-wrapper cv-wrapper");
    $(this).addClass("dv-wrapper");

    $(this).children(0).css({
      opacity: 0.8,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    });
  });

  updatePositions();
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children(0).children(0).removeClass("gv-video cv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).removeClass("gv-details cv-details");
    $(this).children(0).children(0).first().addClass("dv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).last().addClass("dv-details");

    $(this).children(0).animate({
      height: "100px",
      width: "95%",
      opacity: 1,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    }, 1000, "swing");
  });
}


function collapsed() {
  if ($(".wrapper").first().hasClass("cv-wrapper")) return;

  updatePositions();
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("dv-wrapper gv-wrapper");
    $(this).addClass("cv-wrapper");

    $(this).children(0).css({
      opacity: 0.8,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    });
  });

  updatePositions();
  $(".wrapper").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children(0).children(0).removeClass("dv-video gv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).removeClass("dv-details gv-details");
    $(this).children(0).children(0).first().addClass("cv-video");
    $(this).children(0).children(1).last().addClass("cv-details");

    $(this).children(0).animate({
      height: "50px",
      width: "94%",
      opacity: 1,
      top: pos[index].top,
      left: pos[index].left
    }, 1000, "swing");
  });

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  counter-reset: number;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 24px;
}

i.fas {
  margin: 5px;
}

i.fas:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 90vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ADC2A9;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  /* to debug enable the color */
  /*background-color: darkcyan;*/
}

.record {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #D3E4CD;
}

.record:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: counter(number);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: blue
}

.video {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(white 40%, #5e819ef8);
}


/* list view */

.dv-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  float: left;
}

.dv-video {}

.dv-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* grid view */

.gv-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.gv-video {
  float: left;
}

.gv-details {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* collapsed view */

.cv-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
}

.cv-video {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}

.cv-details {
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.details p {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="margin: 0 50%; width: 100px; transform: translate(-50%);">
  <i class="fas fa-list" onclick="detailed()"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-th" onclick="grid()"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="collapsed()"></i>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dv-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="record">
      <div class="video dv-video"></div>
      <div class="details dv-details">
        <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dv-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="record">
      <div class="video dv-video"></div>
      <div class="details dv-details">
        <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dv-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="record">
      <div class="video dv-video"></div>
      <div class="details dv-details">
        <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dv-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="record">
      <div class="video dv-video"></div>
      <div class="details dv-details">
        <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dv-wrapper wrapper">
    <div class="record">
      <div class="video dv-video"></div>
      <div class="details dv-details">
        <p>5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is just a demo code. It can be improved in many ways. We can put wrappers in existing grid or flex containers and animate content items like shown above.
Let me know if any readymade third party available that will reduce or improve above code.

Answer (score 4):

## Code

https://codepen.io/shahriarkh/pen/NWvOyry?editors=0110

Click the "Change Style" button above the grid to toggle animation.

---

Here it is!
I used `grid` because it's animateable, since it's a 2d grid while both `block` and `flex` are 1d.

<s>However, there's a problem with the appearing scroll bar on the right. It's damn annoying and I couldn't find a way to fix it. In line 9 of JS code, every card should move to left by 120px * N, but when the scrollbar appears, it's no longer 120 and becomes a bit larger than 120 (like 126). I don't know where it is coming from... although 120 works fine when you add `overflow-y: hidden` to `body`, it's not an applicable workaround (you need the scroll!).</s>

## Update

I found the solution! Using `overflow-y: scroll` + `scrollbar-width: none` does the trick. However, you need to somehow let users know the page is scrollable.

---

BTW, what's the original video? I'm wondering if it's a webpage and somebody already did this :)
Also, Framer Motion might be a good choice instead of harcoding.

Comment: I really like it :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
It would be great if you can provided the **tile view animation too** like in the video.

Comment: In the video you can see 3 buttons:
**1. Grid view
2. List view
3. Tile view(i,e List view only but animation will be from bottom to top)**
 >> Review the video once, You can see the animation on 3rd button click..

Comment: I see it. I think it's better if you ask it as a separate question :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not exactly look like your desired result, but maybe it´s suitable for u or you can build up on it. i just used a transition on width and an interval to have a small delay in the transform.

```js
function toggle(){
  var k= 0;
  var i = setInterval(function(){
t = $('.test').length;
if(k>t){
 clearInterval(t)
}
$('.test').eq(k).toggleClass("test2");
k++;

  },120)
}

setTimeout(function(){
  toggle()
},1000)
```

```css
.wrap {
  width:500px;
  min-height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.test {
  color:white;
  margin:10px;
  background:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
.test2 {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>

  </div>
```

If u wanted it to be exactly like in the video u would probably have to work with translate-x translate-y